# Green light on my laptop adapter continues to glow for 2 to 3mins, even when it's not charging

Tags: laptop, power-supply, adapter

I can see a Green light on my dell laptop adapter even when adapter is being used and connected to a power source. As per my knowledge this idicates that adapter is plugged in to power source and receiving power.
Upon unplugging the adapter from my power source, green light continues to glow for around 2 to 3 minutes.
Can someone explain me why it is glowing even when the power source is off? what is going on in the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply, in a PSU, there is a large capacitor to level out the power supply to your machine through the transformer circuit.

This leads to a long soak-time for the power to sufficiently dissipate after disconnecting from the mains.

The power wouldn't last long for charging your machine, fractions of a second perhaps, but is more than sufficient to keep the LED lit for some time after unplugging.

Answer (score 1):

> Some light switches run a small amount of current through the bulbs
>   even when off, usually to power small devices at the switch like a
>   timer, motion sensor, or night light. Do your switches have either of
>   those features, or something else like that?
>
> The way those devices work is instead of having a hot/neutral pair
>   powering the switch, they just sit inline with the hot wire and draw a
>   very small amount of power. Old fashioned incandescent bulbs won't
>   light up if there's only a small amount of electricity running through
>   them, so you would never notice this current, but LEDs are much more
>   efficient and apparently are getting enough power to run.
>
> If that is the cause of the problem, there are a few solutions:
>
> ```
> Swap out the light switches for regular ones. You'll lose whatever additional functionality they have.
> Upgrade your switches to ones that have both a neutral and a hot wire, instead of just the hot wire. This may be relatively
> ```
>
> straightforward or extremely difficult, depending on whether the
>   neutral for the light goes through the same box as the switch. (Note
>   that even if you do have a neutral at the box it may be a little
>   tricky to wire it up, since you'll have to cut it and then probably
>   add a pigtail or two.)
>       Put back your old-fashioned incandescents.

And

> If we're talking a high voltage circuit, w high intensity LEDs: Many
>   high intensity white LED's use a phosphor that is in fact
>   phosphorescent, like glow in the dark paint. You just have to wait for
>   it to dim down. Switching to a different brand of bulb, with a
>   different phosphor may help, but it's hard to "try before you buy".
>
> If we're talking a low voltage circuit, 5-12v: A capacitor in line
>   with an LED can power it for quite some time. You can limit this
>   effect by by using a power supply with a smaller filter capacitor.

[Source for both](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30194/why-do-my-led-lights-stay-on-even-when-the-switch-is-off)

Or it's due to the capacitor ([more info](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/capacitor-led-test.22343/))

Comment: not wrong, but the simple answer in a PSU is the capacitor, levelling out the transformer, has a long soak time.

Comment: Surely you should make that an answer then @Tetsujin - I'd upvote it :)!

Comment: I can do - I thought it felt a bit simplistic after your answer ;)